# To represent with a graph

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am preparing a number of charts to show demographic trends. Is there a word meaning *to represent an event with a graph*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use verbal "[graph](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/graph)."

> **graph**: to represent by a graph; to plot (a function) on a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not specifically what you are looking for but:

*Plot* is pretty good

Merriam-Webster:

`5
:  a graphic representation (as a chart)`

Answer (score 0):

You could say "Today I will be showing a graphical representation of {Event}"